# Restrict IP access to Port 443

Tags: webserver

How can restrict access to port 443 on my Debian server. I have an application running on that particular port that I'd like to restrict access to to only one IP: my own.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -s ! 123.123.123.123 -j DROP
```

That should do it.  Replace 123.123.123.123 with your IP.  This basically adds a rule which will drop all connections not from your IP :)

Comment: Wouldn't this conflict with my UFW firewall settings?